# Cucumber DataTable .raw() no longer works (io.cucumber:4.7.2)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Since updating to io.cucumber from info.cukes I cant seem to be able to import raw() and inturn print the value of the DataTable stored in the feature file, any ideas?

```
Scenario: Validate Review Count
Given I access the testimonials homepage
Then the reviews count on the testimonials page should be great than the listed total
| specified total |
| 100             |


public void test(DataTable total) throws Exception {
        List<List<String>> data = total.raw(); //the problem
        System.out.println(data.get(1).get(0));
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the other available methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below method serves the same purpose in io.cucumber:

```
public void test(DataTable total) throws Exception {

    List<List<String>> data = total.asLists(); 
    System.out.println(data.get(1).get(0));
```

}